# Rails Not outputting Highcharts javascript graph

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

I have a rails app on which I'm trying to output a highcharts chart. My javascript code is located in an index.html.erb file and the sample code is as follows:

```
<div id="quote", style="width:560px; height:600px">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
new Highcharts.Chart(
  {
    chart: {renderTo: "quote"}
  },
title: {
  text: "Daily trades" 
},
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime"
},
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: "Shillings"
  }
},
tooltip: {
  formatter: function(){
    return HighCharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + "Kshs" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
  }
},
series: [
<% { "Telecommunication" => StockQuote.telecomm, "Agriculture" => StockQuote.agric }.each do |name, prices|
%>
{
  name: <%= name %>
  pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
  pointStart: <%= 2.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
  data: <%= (2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| StockQuote.price_on(date).to_f}.inspect%>
},
<% end %>
]
);
});
</scipt>
</div>
```

However instead of showing me a blank section on the quote div where the chart is supposed to be, it shows me my actual javascript code.

My application.html.erb file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Abacus</title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.11.0.min", "highcharts" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>

 <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have included jquery-rails gem, and jquery-ui-rails gems and bundled them and followed the steps on their github pages on how to require them.

My application.js has the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Just a note: on your closing script tag you've got </scipt> instead of </script>

Answer (score 0):

You should put the javascript in a script block like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
new Highcharts.Chart(
  {
    chart: {renderTo: "quote"}
  }
);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've changed, but now instead nothing is being shown when I reload the page. Check my edit to see the changes

Comment: Check my edit to see my full code, might the problem be the dynamic erb tags where I'm using ruby to change data that is going to be in the graph